# TCL: exec egrep "child process exited abnormally"

Tags: tcl

I have a problem with egrep command.
When I execute my command in tcsh it is working perfect but when I execute it from tcl script or in tclsh, I got:

***child process exited abnormally***

My tcl code:

```
exec egrep -i "^(\\\s+)?(tvf::)?LAYOUT\\\s+PATH" test_file
```

The test_file contain

```
LAYOUT PATH "file1"
  LAYOUT PATH "file2"
//LAYOUT FILE "file 3"
foo string
tvf::LAYOUT PATH "file4"
  tvf::LAYOUT PATH "file5"
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Hello all,

I did some additional investigations and run this command also on 32 bit machine.
The command works properly with 32 bit egrep

Result:

```
LAYOUT PATH "file1"
    LAYOUT PATH "file2"
tvf::LAYOUT PATH "file3"
      tvf::LAYOUT PATH "file3"
```

*file /bin/egrep*
*/bin/egrep: symbolic link to `grep'*

*file /bin/grep*
*/bin/grep: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped*

But when I remove additional backslashes :

```
exec egrep -i "^(\s+)?(tvf::)?LAYOUT\s+PATH" test_file
```

The command return error:

***child process exited abnormally***

The egrep version on 64 bit machine is:

*file /bin/egrep*
*/bin/egrep: symbolic link to `grep'*

*file /bin/grep*
*/bin/grep: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped*

Comment: My, what a lot of backslashes you've got there…

Comment: Hello Donal, without these additional backslashes the command return error on 32 bit machine

Comment: Putting REs in `{` braces `}` would let you reduce the number, as nothing would need quoting.

Comment: And “32 bit machine” is just the biggest red herring ever. The size of the machine word and the address space has **nothing** to do with your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

grep uses its exit status to indicate presence/absence of a match ([man page](http://man.cx/grep)) - if no matches the exit status is 1. Tcl's `exec` treats any non-zero exit status as an exceptional situation. You need to `catch` the exec call, check the return value from catch and if nonzero examine the `$errorCode` variable. A thorough example here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec, click "Show Discussion" and scroll down to KBK's example.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when running the following command:

```
exec top -b -n 1 -c | egrep lnx64.o/vsimk | wc -l
```

TCL wasn't happy about forward slash "/" in the grep expression.
It got fixed by using "-ignorestderr" switch:

```
exec -ignorestderr -- top -b -n 1 -c | egrep lnx64.o/vsimk | wc -l.
```